# How can I make a window or NSPanel out of an image?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I'm trying to add some style to my app and it's driving me crazy. I'm wanting to take a image that is transparent and use it as a window or NSPanel. I'm thinking this will have to be done programmatically but I would like to do it in Interface Builder. How can I achieve this effect either way. So far, I've tried both ways and can't achieve it. Any code examples would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: So, you want a borderless window showing nothing but an image?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make a [borderless window](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSBorderlessWindowMask), and set an [image view](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImageView_Class/) as its content view, and set the image as the image view's image.